# How can I trigger this 'typeof(undefined) != undefined' error? Undefined doesn't do the trick... JS

Tags: javascript, undefined

I have a function:

```
function goError(thing){

    console.log(typeof(thing)); //RETURNS A STRING 'UNDEFINED'

    if(typeof(thing) != undefined){
        console.log(thing); //RETURNS UNDEFINED
        return thing;
    }

    throw 'Error: ' + thing;
}
```

I'm trying to get down to the error message. But when I pass through a parameter of `undefined`, the function works correctly, which is not what I want.

When I console out the undefined variable, I get `undefined`, but when I console out `typeof(thing)` I get a string `'undefined'`.  This string obviously isnt causing my error to kick in.

I could alter the function as follows, it works fine then and I can get to my error.

```
    if(thing != undefined){
        return thing;
    }
```

**But can I cause the error to kick in without altering the func?**

What can I pass into my function that will cause the error?

Comment: correct, `typoeof` returns the type as a string, so you should write `typeof thing !== 'undefined'` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: So the function is incorrect as it currently is written?

Answer (score 2):

To check if `thing` is `undefined`, you must do:

```
if(typeof thing !== "undefined") {
    // well, it seems to have something
}
```

And [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xzgfy6ew/), if needed.

Comment: it should be `typeof thing !== "undefined"`

Comment: both works, but fixed, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code

```
function goError(thing){    

    if(thing){        
        return thing;
    }
    throw 'Error: ' + thing;
}
```

Comment: the original code is only checking for `undefined`, not `""`, or `0`, or `null`, etc

Answer (score 1):

Seeing that you're using Angular, you can use the `angular.isDefined` utility method, [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.isDefined):

```
function goError(thing){

    if(angular.isDefined(thing)){
        return thing;
    }

    throw 'Error: ' + thing;
}
```